# How to delete record from grid on delete in extjs4

Tags: grid, extjs4, delete-record

I am working in extjs4. I have view with grid as item with code:

```
{
            margin : '10 0 5 100',
            xtype : 'grid',
            id : 'g3',
            //title : 'Educational Details',
             store:'qb.qbquestionoptionStore',
            columns : [ {
                text : 'questionId',
                dataIndex : 'questionId',
                flex : 1
            },

            {
                text : 'category',
                dataIndex : 'category',
                flex : 1
            }, {
                text : 'Answer',
                dataIndex : 'isAnswer',
                flex : 2.5
            },
            {
                header : 'Remove',
                renderer : function(val) {
                    return '<a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a>';
                },
            }
```

So on clicking on remove link,corresponding entry gets deleted from database. But grid is still showing that deleted entry. In controller I have code for it as-

```
deleterow:function(cmp)
            {
                 cmp.mon(cmp.getEl(),'click',function(event,target)
                      {
                  if(target.id=='remove')
                  {  
                    // alert("hello");

                       listview=Ext.getCmp('g3');

                      listview.on({
                          itemClick: function(dv, record, item, index, e,opts)
                          {
                              liststore=this.getStore('qb.qbquestioncomplexityStore').sync();
                              liststore.load({
                                  params:{
                                      id:record.data.id,
                                      questionId:record.data.questionId

                                  }
                              });
                              console.log(record);
                              console.log(" Id is "+record.data.id);
                         var shopCart=Ext.create('Balaee.model.qb.qbquestioncomplexityModel', 
                                      {
                                  id:record.data.id,
                                  questionId:record.data.questionId
                                      });
                              Ext.Msg.confirm('Confirm to delete', 'Want to delete record?', function (button) 
                                      {
                                  if (button == 'yes')
                                  {
                                     shopCart.destroy();

                                  }
                                      }); }
                      });  }
             },this,{delegate:"a"});

            },
```

So how to delete record from grid?.

Answer (score 2):

to remove a row from `gridpanel`, i do something like this:

```
var selectedRecord = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
grid.getStore().each(function(rec) {
    if (rec == selectedRecord) {
        grid.store.remove(rec);
    }
});
grid.getView().refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit weird but I think you are nearly there:

The easiest way is when you have set a proxy to the model. You just need to call [destroy()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-destroy). Any stores this record is bound to will be notified.

```
if (button == 'yes'){
    record.destroy();
    shopCart.destroy();
}
```

If not I assume for this example that your record is only bound to one store, then you can do it like

```
if (button == 'yes'){
    var s = record.store;
    s.remove(record);
    s.store.sync();
    shopCart.destroy();
}
```

Comment: thanx for help...If i use "record.store.remove(record);
    record.store.sync();
    shopCart.destroy();" its giving me error as-Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'sync' of null

Comment: Thanx for reply....I am following way you have suggested. But now its giving me error as-"Uncaught Ext.data.proxy.Server.buildUrl(): You are using a ServerProxy but have not supplied it with a url.". I am using model's proxy. So what changes i need to do

Comment: @user1722857 This is simple, use my first code-snipped not the second. The first is for model proxy the second for store proxy

Comment: thanx for reply..I included code as-"if (button == 'yes'){
    record.destroy();
    shopCart.destroy();
}"  But still its not deleting records from grid....